# Why am I getting DllNotFoundException when adding SQLite Nuget Package to LINQPad?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, linqpad

I have added the `System.Data.SQLite.Core` NuGet package to my LINQPad 5 Query (Premium) and then try to execute the following:

```
new SQLiteConnection(":memory:").Dump();
```

But I get:

> DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The
>   specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E)

How can I tell LINQPad where to find the SQLite Native DLLs?

Please note I do not want to use the IQ Driver.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This library is not referenced in the standard way, because it's native and requires different images for X86 and X64.

A workaround in LINQPad is to locate the following folder:

```
%localappdata%\LINQPad\NuGet.FW46\System.Data.SQLite.Core\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.99.0\build\net46
```

and copy the **X86** and **X64** subfolders into the folder where LINQPad.exe is located.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, based on [this comment in the LINQPad forum](http://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/comment/384/#Comment_384), is to do the following:

1. Copy the *System.Data.SQLite.dll* file (and probably also the corresponding *System.Data.SQLite.xml* file too) somewhere, e.g. in the same directory as your LINQPad query file.
2. Copy the *x64* and *x86* sub-directories, e.g. from the directory *C:\Users\your-user-name-goes-here\AppData\Local\LINQPad\NuGet.FW46\System.Data.SQLite\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.103\build\net46*, to the same directory you copied the file in step [1].
3. Add the following code to your LINQPad query:

   ```
   System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(
       "PreLoadSQLite_BaseDirectory",
       @"C:\path\to\which\you\copied\the\files\and\directories\in\steps\one\and\two");
   ```

The advantage of this relative to the answer submitted by Joe Albahari (the creator of LINQPad by-the-way!) is that this could be readily included in a Git repo (were you to be storing your LINQPad query thusly).